# Show that an compact operator in a Hilbert space can be written as the product of an isometry and a positive operator

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $T: H \rightarrow H$ a compact operator. Show that there are bounded operators $S, U: H \rightarrow H$, with $S \ge 0$ and $U$ restrict to $N(T)^\perp$ an isometry, such that $T = US$ and $\|Tx\| = \|S\|$ for every $x \in H$.
> Hint: Show that $T^*T \ge 0$ and consider $\sqrt{T^*T}$.

I'm stuck at the hint, couldn't figure how I'm supposed to prove that $T^*T \ge 0$. Also, is $\sqrt{T^*T}$ supposed to be the $S$? I don't know.

Comment: What is your definition of $\geq$ in this context? It should suffice to show that $\langle T^*Tx, x \rangle \geq 0$ holds for all $x \in H$.

Comment: And yes, $\sqrt{T^*T}$ is supposed to be the $S$.

Comment: This is known as the *polar decomposition* and it actually holds for all bounded operators, not necessarily compact.

Comment: The operator $U$ is called a *partial isometry* because it is only isometric on the orthogonal complement of its kernel.  To be a true isometry an operator must satisfy $\|U(x)\|=\|x\|$, for **all** $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further hints:

- To show that $T^*T \geq 0$, show that $\langle T^*Tx, x \rangle \geq 0$ holds for all $x \in H$.
- Note that $N(T)^\perp$ is the closure of the image of $T^*T$, and with that in mind define $U$ on $N(T)^\perp$ so that
  $$
  U[\sqrt{T^*T}x] = Tx.
  $$
  Why does $\|Tx\| = \|\sqrt{T^*T}x\|$ hold for $x \in H$?
- We can linearly extend $U$ by taking $U$ to do anything we want over $N(T)$. For instance, we can take $U|_{N(T)} = 0$.

Comment: Why is $N(T)^\perp = R(T^*T)$? I can show that $T^*T \subseteq N(T)^\perp$ using the internal product, but I couldn't prove the other inclusion.

Comment: Sorry, that was incorrect: that should be $N(T)^\perp$ is the closure of the image of $T^*T$. This holds because $N(T) = R(T^*T)^\perp$.

Comment: By what result can we define an isometry $U$ such that $U[\sqrt{T^*T}x] = Tx$?

Comment: It's sufficient to note that $\|\sqrt{T^*T}x\| = \|Tx\|$

Comment: That said, the fact that this is sufficient might require the [Mazur Ulam theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazur%E2%80%93Ulam_theorem); I don't know if there's an easier way to see this

Comment: Alternatively, since the restriction $(T^*T)^{1/2}|_{N(T)^\perp}$ has a trivial kernel, we could essentially define $U|_{N(T)} = (T^*T)^{-1/2}T$.

Comment: Whenever two operators $T$ and $S$ satisfy $\|T(x)\|\leq\|S(x)\|$, there is a contractive linear operator $U$, defined on the range of $S$, such that $US=T$. To see this, take any $y$ in the range of $S$, write it as $S(x)$ and put $U(y)=T(x)$.  One needs to show that $U$ is well defined and contractive, but this is very easy!  Once this is done one may continuously extend $U$ to the closure of the range of $S$, and from there to the whole space by setting it to be zero on the orthogonal complement.